# Drive API Error: python doesn't found json quickstart file

Tags: python, google-drive-api, google-oauth

I'm trying to use Google-drive-api and I have a problem. I followed accurately every instructions of the quickstart tutorial for google Drive api and I have an error with a file that I don't have. 
[Python quickstart tutorial](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/python)
Here is my code :

```
from __future__ import print_function
import httplib2
import os

from apiclient import discovery
from oauth2client import client
from oauth2client import tools
from oauth2client.file import Storage

try:
    import argparse
    flags = argparse.ArgumentParser(parents=[tools.argparser]).parse_args()
except ImportError:
    flags = None

# If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials
# at ~/.credentials/drive-python-quickstart.json
SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata'
CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = 'client_secret.json'
APPLICATION_NAME = 'Drive API Python Quickstart'


def get_credentials():
    """Gets valid user credentials from storage.

    If nothing has been stored, or if the stored credentials are invalid,
    the OAuth2 flow is completed to obtain the new credentials.

    Returns:
        Credentials, the obtained credential.
    """
    home_dir = os.path.expanduser('~')
    credential_dir = os.path.join(home_dir, '.credentials')
    if not os.path.exists(credential_dir):
        os.makedirs(credential_dir)
    credential_path = os.path.join(credential_dir,
                                   'drive-python-quickstart.json')

    store = Storage(credential_path)
    credentials = store.get()
    if not credentials or credentials.invalid:
        flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, SCOPES)
        flow.user_agent = APPLICATION_NAME
        if flags:
            credentials = tools.run_flow(flow, store, flags)
        else: # Needed only for compatibility with Python 2.6
            credentials = tools.run(flow, store)
        print('Storing credentials to ' + credential_path)
    return credentials

def main():
    """Shows basic usage of the Google Drive API.

    Creates a Google Drive API service object and outputs the names and IDs
    for up to 10 files.
    """
    credentials = get_credentials()
    http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
    service = discovery.build('drive', 'v3', http=http)

    results = service.files().list(
        pageSize=10,fields="nextPageToken, files(id, name)").execute()
    items = results.get('files', [])
    if not items:
        print('No files found.')
    else:
        print('Files:')
        for item in items:
            print('{0} ({1})'.format(item['name'], item['id']))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Result :

> C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\oauth2client_helpers.py:255:
>   UserWarning: Cannot access
>   C:\Users\Neyoh.credentials\drive-python-quickstart.json: No such file
>   or directorywarnings.warn(_MISSING_FILE_MESSAGE.format(filename))

I have the `client_secret.json` file in the directory of my python script but in `HOME/.credentials/` , I have nothing.
The tutorial speaks about `client_secret.json` but not about `drive-python-quickstart.json` . It's never mentioned. 
What is `drive-python-quickstart.json` ? Is the same file ?

Edit1 : When I use `client_secret.json` in `\.credentials\` instead of `drive-python-quickstart.json` I have this error :

> File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\oauth2client\client.py", line 302,
>   in new_from_json module_name = data['_module'] KeyError: '_module'

Comment: @DaImTo When i used `client_secret.json` , I have this error: `File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\oauth2client\client.py", line 302, in new_from_json
    module_name = data['_module'] KeyError: '_module' `

Comment: I found, `drive-python-quickstart.json` must be an empty file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I went into the same issue with google calendar api. 
To solve the problem simply use the absolute file path to your `CLIENT_SECRET_FILE` like:

```
CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = r'C:\Users\xxx\client_secret.json'
```

The file `drive-python-quickstart.json` will be created **after** authentication automatically.